# Fill multidimesional array with values of another array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, insert, associative-array

I've this array as query result:

```
[0]=>
array(2) {
["id_iscr"]=>
int(2)
["id_pettorina"]=>
NULL
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
["id_iscr"]=>
int(3)
["id_pettorina"]=>
NULL
}
[2]=>
array(2) {
["id_iscr"]=>
int(5)
["id_pettorina"]=>
NULL
}
[3]=>
array(2) {
["id_iscr"]=>
int(7)
["id_pettorina"]=>
NULL
}
...
```

and this as array of distinct value

```
[0]=>
int(125)
[1]=>
int(162)
[2]=>
int(65)
[3]=>
int(98)
...
```

Both array have same number of element;
my question is: in which way can I fill each NULL value of the first array with each value of the socond one and insert into mysql db?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start writing a code, `foeach` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the code, but what Iam doing here is: Loop entire array1, verifying if the value is null, and if it is, I get the same position from the array2 and fill into `id_pettorina` position and save into a new resulting array called `$resultingArray`.

```
<?php
$resultingArray = array();
foreach ($array1 as $k => $value) {
    if ($value["id_pettorina"] == null) {
        $value["id_pettorina"] = $array2[$k];
    }
    $resultingArray[] = $value;

    //Here in can insert into database, according to your schema
}
```

In the line commented, you may insert the data from `$resultingArray` inside your database, using the values inside `$value` array. ex: `$query = "INSERT INTO yourdbname SET id_pettorina = '".$value["id_pettorina"]."'";`. Then you may pass this query into your statement and execute.

Answer (score 0):

@sihciv simply use if condition inside foreach() like below:

```
<?php
    $arr1 = array(
                array(
                    "id_iscr"=> 2,
                    "id_pettorina"=> NULL
                ),
                array(
                    "id_iscr"=> 3,
                    "id_pettorina"=> NULL
                ),
                array(
                    "id_iscr"=> 5,
                    "id_pettorina"=> NULL
                ),
                array(
                    "id_iscr"=> 7,
                    "id_pettorina"=> NULL
                )
            );
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr1); //array before
    $arr2 = array(125,162,65,98);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
        foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
            if($value1 == null){
                if(isset($arr2[$i])){
                    $arr1[$key][$key1] = $arr2[$i];
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr1); //array after
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
for ($i=0; i<count(array); i++) 
  array[i]['id_pettorina'] = other_array[i];
```

Inserting it into MySQL depends on your database API

Comment: in php you should use `count(array)`. If I remember, `array.length` is JS.